Prove that the foot of an altitude from the apex of a tetrahedron lies on the altitude of the base triangle

In this figure, let $\text{DX}$ be the altitude of $\triangle ABD$, and $\text{CX}$ is given to also be the altitude of $\triangle ABC$. Prove that the foot altitude Y, of $ABC$ with regard to apex $D$ lies on $\text{CX}$
This is a step I need to prove the following question, which is Problem 9 from AIME 1984

In tetrahedron $ABCD$, edge $AB$ has length 3 cm. The area of face $ABC$ is $15\mbox{cm}^2$ and the area of face $ABD$ is $12 \mbox { cm}^2$. These two faces meet each other at a $30^\circ$ angle. Find the volume of the tetrahedron in $\mbox{cm}^3$.

Once I can prove this, I will be further able to find DY, and thus find the volume of the tetrahedron

Can you elaborate on how these 2 questions are related? I don't think they are (unless you added more assumptions). EG If $ \angle DAB = 90^\circ, \angle CBA = 90^\circ$, then the do not have a common altitude foot to $AB$.         $\quad$ FWIW In the AIME problem, you can make some assumptions like $\angle DAB = 90^\circ, \angle CAB =90 ^\circ$ to determine the numerical answer.

Right, so if I can prove the height from D to CX is the altitude of the tetrahedron, then in $\triangle DXC$, the area is $(DX)(CX)sin(30)$, or written alternatively as $\frac{(DY)(CX)}{2}$, and you can find $DY$ to be 4. Then the volume of the tetrahedron is $\frac{4*15}{3}$ = 20

Also, how are yo allowed to make those assumptions in the AIME problem? Another solution said you can assume that $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ABC$ are isosceles, but that felt like a cheat

1/ My point is that you can't "prove the height from D to CX is the altitude", because it's not always true. $\quad$ 2/ The AIME only requires numerical answers, and you don't have to show your work, so you can do whatever you want to get at it. EG See AOPS Solution 3 Sketchy $\quad$  It is rare that such assumptions could simplify an AIME problem though, I thought they were better designed than that.

Oh, right, that clarifies my doubt thanks. But what would an assumptionless solution look like

See AOPS solution 2 rigorous.  $\quad$ Because the height of D in an invariant, we can make whatever assumptions we want to find the volume.
